# Why does a increasing function in compact interval have both $f(c+)$ and $f(c-)$?

Tags: real-analysis

In book "Mathematical Analysis" by T.Apostol 1974, In theorem 4.51 page 95 said: if $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ then both of $f(c+)$ and $f(c-)$ are exist and $a<c<b$.
To prove of this theorem the book said: "... But since $\alpha=\sup A$, there is an element $f(x_1)$ of $A$ such that $\alpha-\epsilon<f(x_1)\leq\alpha$. Since $f$ is increasing for every $x$ in $(x_1,c)$ we also have $\alpha-\epsilon<f(x)\leq\alpha$ ...".
But it is possible when $f$ is continuous but if not?, for example suppose $f$ is 
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x <  - 1\\
 - 1/2\,\,\,x =  - 1/2\\
0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0\\
1/2\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 1/2\\
x\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x > 1
\end{array} \right.$$

and interval is $[-2,2]$ and $c=0$ then $f$ is increasing on $[-2,2]$ and $A=[-2,-1) \cup \{-1/2\}$ therefore $\sup A=-1/2$ and $x_1=-1/2$. But for $x\in (-1/2,0)$, $f(x)$ is not defined so we do not have $α−ϵ<f(x)≤α$. if $f$ is continuous, proof is correct, but in this case is not?.

Comment: A monotonic function on $[a,b]$ must be defined for every $c\in[a,b]$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Certainly your $f$ isn't continuous on $[-1,1]$ because it isn't defined on most of it. Furthering Jack's comment, **any** function has to be defined on its whole domain.

Comment: Thank you  Jack D'Aurizio.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has little to do with continuity. Here $f(c-)$ is defined to be the limit $\lim_{x \to c-} f(x)$, and this has a cost: $c$ must be a (left) accumulation point of the domain of $f$. In your example $1/2$ is isolated for the domain, and you can't expect anything about limits.

By the way, Apostol is assuming here that $f$ is defined on a superset of $[a,b]$, and hence each point in $[a,b]$ is an accumulation point of the domain. In particular all your "counterexample" becomes rather meaningless.